# Using protobuf with golang and handling []byte HTTP response body

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I am using the Golang protobuf package and try to write some tests to ensure my API works properly.

I construct an Object on the server-side with a generated `.pb.go` file.

And return it with

```
data, err := proto.Marshal(p)
fmt.Fprint(w, data)
```

And in my test I do

```
func TestGetProduct(t *testing.T) {
    log.Println("Starting server")
    go startAPITestServer()
    time.Sleep(0 * time.Second)
    log.Println("Server started")
    //rq, err := http.NewRequest("GET", "localhost:8181/product/1", nil)
    client := &http.Client{}
    log.Println("Starting Request")
    resp, err := client.Get("http://localhost:8181/product/1")
    log.Println("Finished Request")
    if err != nil {
        t.Log(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    log.Println("Reading Request")
    data, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    log.Println("Reading finished")
    if err != nil {
        t.Log(err)
    }
    log.Println("HTTP Resp", data)
    p := &Product{}
    proto.UnmarshalText(string(data), p)
    proto.Unmarshal(data, p2)
}
```

The Problem is that the HTTP Request is correct and displays the `[]byte` correctly, but if I do `ioutil.ReadAll` it interprets the HTTP Response as a string and converts it to a `[]byte`.

For example the response is

```
[12 3 2 14 41]
```

Then `ioutil.ReadAll` interprets this as a string and not as a `[]byte`.

Comment: In your `log.Println(data)` if you want a byte slice to be formatted as something other a byte slice you need to either covert (e.g. `string(data)`) or use formatting (e.g. `log.Printf("HTTP Resp: % 02X", data)`, or `"%s"` maybe).

Comment: @DaveC the problem is not the log it's 
Sending []byte Data over HTTP, receiving this []byte Data and encoding it back into the correct []byte Data

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was: I tried to write binary data to the output stream with `fmt.Fprint` missing the important fact, that the `fmt` package converts (everything?) input to a "read-able" format (ie strings).
The correct way of writting data into the output of your HTTP Response is using the responsewriter directly like this:

```
k, err := w.Write(data)
```